# (vb 2010) object continue moving, but stop when i hit a button. When i add a button the entire code stops

Tags: vb.net

I need to make an object continue moving when arrow keys are pressed, but stop when i hit a button. When I add a button the entire  code stops.

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Do While e.KeyCode = Keys.Left
        If PictureBox1.Left = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        PictureBox1.Left -= 1
    Loop
    Do While e.KeyCode = Keys.Right
        If PictureBox1.Left = 877 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        PictureBox1.Left += 1
    Loop
    Do While e.KeyCode = Keys.Up

        If PictureBox1.Top = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        PictureBox1.Top -= 1
    Loop
    Do While e.KeyCode = Keys.Down

        If PictureBox1.Top = 420 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        PictureBox1.Top += 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app stops because it is stuck in the loop inside the `KeyDown` event for as long as the key is held down and never gets any idle time to process pending Windows Messages (such as repainting).

The easy, **and incredibly bad**, way to "fix" this would be to call `Application.DoEvents` inside each Loop.  This will manually tell your application to process the pending messages.  For any kind of serious work you want to avoid this method though, as it is a "Code Smell" that usually means you are doing something wrong.  For a well written application there is *usually* no reason to ever manually call `Application.DoEvents`.

You would be better off changing it to use a timer with a low interval that periodically checks the state of the keyboard and handles advancing the state of the application by one "tick" at a time.

Comment: Thank you. im just now learning to code in vb, and i need all the help i can get, so thanks for the help!